# Draft function of a stand-by question

Tags: support, asking-questions, draft, editor

Does there exist a possibility on the site to save a draft of a question I am writing up, such that it will remain even if I leave the site but come back to it later?

Comment: It's automatic. All you have to do is write a question. It is saved. The next time you open it, you'll find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a network-wide functionality that has been implemented since 2010 (with some modifications over time):

> If you start asking a question, but do not successfully submit, you will see your last saved question draft the next time you visit the ask a question page.
>
> If you start answering a particular question, but do not successfully submit, you will see your last saved answer draft the next time you visit that particular question page.
>
> We save drafts automatically for all new answers and new questions once every 45 seconds.
>
> - Drafts are not supported on self-answer.
> - Drafts are not supported on edits.
> - You only get **one** draft for an answer and one for a question. (If you start a new post, the old draft is cleared.)
> - Each site has its own draft storage, e.g. you can have multiple draft questions saved on multiple StackExchange sites
> - Drafts will be automatically cleared after a week.
> - Drafts work for anonymous users as well.
>
> Also:
>
> - Pending answer draft is cleared on successful submission of any answer.
> - Pending question draft is cleared on successful submission of any question.

Reference: [Allow questions to be saved as drafts prior to posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1177/168244)